# How to add a document to a firestore document subcollection

Tags: firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to add a document to a document's sub collection but it doesn't work (code execution hangs at the first await). The code is running in the browser with firebase 6.4.0.

```
const docRef = await firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(uid)
  .collection('lists')
  .add({
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    updatedAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    title,
    description
  });
const docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
```

I tried to express the path using `users/${uid}/lists` but this doesn't change anything.

The firestore rules are correctly set:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I could make it work using an intermediary get() on the user's document but I feel that's should not be necessary:

```
const userSnapshot = await firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(uid)
  .get();
const docRef = await userSnapshot.ref.collection('lists').add({
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  updatedAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  title,
  description
});
const docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
```

Am I doing something wrong in the first code snippet?

Thanks in advance for your help ;-)

EDIT: like I said in the comments, this is consumed by redux-thunk, here's the full method implementation:

```
export const createList = (
  title: string,
  description: string
): ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, CreateListActions> => async (
  dispatch,
  getState
) => {
  const { uid } = getState().auth.currentUser!;

  dispatch(createListStarted({ title, description }));

  try {
    const listReference = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(uid)
      .collection('lists')
      .add({
        createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        updatedAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        title,
        description
      });
    const listSnapshot = await listReference.get();
    const list = toObject<List>(listSnapshot);

    dispatch(createListSucceeded(list));
    history.push('/lists');
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(createListFailed(error));
  }
};
```

Comment: I am adding data in sub collections in one of my project and i am doing it exactly like. There may be some other error here.

Comment: Azzam Asghar is right. From a pure Firebase perspective, the code seems correct. How do you use it? Is it included in an async function? Do you see any error in the browser Console?

Comment: Maybe try changing `title, description` to `title:title, description:description`. Not really sure about this. Never used firestore in  `title, description` way.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm using it inside an async function that is consumed by redux-thunk (code added in original post). Redux plumbering is working fine for other firebase related stuff like sign in/up.

No, it can't be the document structure, title:title or title alone is sugar syntax from javascript.

What really bugs me is that it works if I get() the parent document first. It really shouldn't be like that.

Comment: Thats very strange. I have the following code and its working totally fine.
`const customerRef = db.collection('customers').doc(uid);
customerRef.collection('sources').add(data)`

Comment: @FabianVilers Do you see something in an error log? Web Console?

Comment: No, the code just hangs, no error thrown, empty console. :-(

Comment: Maybe try using promise to see if there are any errors thrown?

Comment: Found why, see answer. Thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug in the firebase package version 6.4.0. I installed the 6.3.5 version and the issue has disappeared!